# Bootstrap laravel environment in test file

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

I often like to test my class methods (before writing actual unit tests) by creating a simple PHP file that instantiates the class, and then messing with the variables in XDebug.

I've created a file for testing called `testing.php` in the root of the laravel site, and I just want to execute this file and see if the objects interact as I'm expecting. I can't quite get the app to bootstrap correctly however. The file looks like:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

use App\User;

$user = User::find(1); // there's a breakpoint on this line

$a = true;
```

When I execute this (run debug in phpstorm) I get an error from the DB connection not being found:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /opt/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1285
```

Apparently there's an additional step(s) that I need to take to make this work-- does anyone know how to get the DB connections working?

Comment: Check out `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` to see how they bootstrap the application. You can also just run `php artisan tinker testing.php` which will do the bootstrapping for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "start" the application before using it.

```php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/** @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app */
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

$app->bootstrapWith([
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
]);

$app->boot();

$app->registerConfiguredProviders();

dd(User::find(12341234));
```